# Make certain part of form scrollable

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have to fit in at least 30 buttons in the red box below without stretching the form size. (Buttons are generated by array)

My question is... is there a way to make the certain part of the form scroll-able. If not, is listview or list box only option?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them in a `Panel` control, then set [`AutoScroll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll.aspx) to true.

Answer (score 1):

Add all the buttons in a FlowLayoutPanel, 
with FlowDirection=TopDown and AutoScroll=true

Answer (score 0):

try this:

set desired height and width of the scrollable area.

```
<div style="height: 500px; width: 400px; overflow: scroll;">

<%--Add your buttons inside this div, you may give an id to this div and make it runat server--%>

</div>
```